# Unhandled event loop exception in Eclipse 4.3 Java EE

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, glassfish

I was trying to do the first steps in Java EE with this tutorial [Java EE/Glassfish Tutorial](http://www.objectdb.com/tutorial/jpa/eclipse/ee>)
I'm using the latest glassfish-, eclipse- and java-version on a windows 7 32-Bit PC with two monitors. But I get the following error when running the servlet on the server.
The first few lines of error log:

message: Unhandled event loop exception
    java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.ole.win32.COM.VtblCall(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.ole.win32.IDispatch.Invoke(IDispatch.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.swt.ole.win32.OleAutomation.invoke(OleAutomation.java:571)
    at org.eclipse.swt.ole.win32.OleAutomation.invoke(OleAutomation.java:534)
    at org.eclipse.swt.browser.IE.navigate(IE.java:1285)
    at org.eclipse.swt.browser.IE.setUrl(IE.java:1464)
    at org.eclipse.swt.browser.IE$7.handleEvent(IE.java:542)
    at org.eclipse.swt.ole.win32.OleEventTable.sendEvent(OleEventTable.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.swt.ole.win32.OleEventSink.notifyListener(OleEventSink.java:152)
    at org.eclipse.swt.ole.win32.OleEventSink.Invoke(OleEventSink.java:120)
    at org.eclipse.swt.ole.win32.OleEventSink.access$1(OleEventSink.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.swt.ole.win32.OleEventSink$1.method6(OleEventSink.java:71)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.ole.win32.COMObject.callback6(COMObject.java:119)
    ...
the first few lines repeats for ~50 times until it ends with:
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.ole.win32.COM.VtblCall(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.ole.win32.IDispatch.Invoke(IDispatch.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.swt.ole.win32.OleAutomation.invoke(OleAutomation.java:571)
    at org.eclipse.swt.ole.win32.OleAutomation.invoke(OleAutomation.java:534)
    at org.eclipse.swt.browser.IE.navigate(IE.java:1285)
    at org.eclipse.swt.browser.IE.setUrl(IE.java:1464)
    at org.eclipse.swt.browser.Browser.setUrl(Browser.java:1125)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.browser.BrowserViewer.navigate(BrowserViewer.java:625)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.browser.BrowserViewer.setURL(BrowserViewer.java:666)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.browser.BrowserViewer.setURL(BrowserViewer.java:287)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.browser.BrowserViewer$10.handleEvent(BrowserViewer.java:736)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1057)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4170)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3759)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1113)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:997)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:610)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:567)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:354)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:181)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:591)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1450)

Session data:
eclipse.buildId=4.3.0.M20130911-1000
java.version=1.7.0_45
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=de_DE
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product

Hopefully some of you has a guess what the problem might be. I already tried a completely new installation of java, eclipse, glassfish, etc. Even a downgrade on eclipse 3.7. Other entries here supposed that the two monitors might be the reason, but I also tried to switch one monitor off.